# Database limit for influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am getting this issue while storing the data in influxdb. The logs are generating as data is stored but when it comes to influxdb I am unable to find the data in the measurement. I thought it may be due to database size limit but for other measurements the data is getting inserted and no issue with them. So, if you have any idea about how to check measurement size or any more ideas to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on InfluxDB v1.x, you could use [influx_inspect's report-disk](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/influx_inspect/#report-disk).

If you are on InfluxDB v2.x, you take advantage of the internal stats as following:

```
from(bucket: "yourBucket")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "storage_shard_disk_size")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "gauge")
    |> last()
```